# How to setState on an array of object in react

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux, setstate

I'm working on a multiple checkbox filter.

I have the state like this:

```
this.state = {
    filter: [
        {
            "elements": [],
            "filterKey": ''
        }
    ]
};
```

For example, in filterKey I will have departments and, in elements, I'll have: Productions, Marketing, etc.
When I press on a checkbox, I want to set the state, but the checkbox is in another component:

```
const DepartmentRow = ({ data }) =>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><div><input type="checkbox" name="ListOfDepartments" value={data.department} onChange={handleCheckboxForDepartments}/>
      <label htmlFor="ListOfDepartments">{data.department}</label></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>;

DepartmentRow.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object
};

export default DepartmentRow;
```

First, I'm trying to find a way to import handleCheckboxForDepartments function in the component where I have the state.
And in handleCheckboxForDepartments, I want to set the state for dispatching an action, because on the server we already have the filtered list, and it needs me to send that array of objects.

But to me, it's a little bit difficult to set the State having this form...

```
handleCheckboxForDepartments(event) {
    this.setState({ filter ..});
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: you're getting confusing, why you should `setState` if you're working with `actions` (which suppose a `state manager`)?

Comment: as @Hitmands said, are you really using a state manager like `redux`?

Comment: Because I dispatch an action having the state as param, and that action will call a service, that will send that information to the server, and will receive a filtered list.

Comment: Yes..I must say that I'm a begginer. I'm not so good. Lot of stuff is confusing for me.

Comment: rework your question with: 1. example of your initial state, 2. example of how your state should look like after. (if you're using `redux`, consider to move the react state to the store).